# copy/paste range with formula to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I may be stupid, but I can't find a simple way to copy/paste a range of formula from  ***ws1*** to ***ws*** in the same workbook. I want to avoid the heavy and unsuitable `Range.select select.copy Sheet("X").select ...` story.

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("TT.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("B")
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("A")
<-----more code------->
 Sheets("A").Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(41, 7)).Copy _
 Destination:=Sheets("B").Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(41, 7))
```

Returns an error. Same if I catch the expression between a `With wb [code] End With`.

```
 ws1.Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(41, 7)).Formula = ws.Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(41, 7)).Formula
```

Returns Range method has failed, `With wb` or not.

I must be missing something, but can't see what! Thank you for your light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify the Cells objects (*right hand side of the equation*)

and for the below you need to have `ws1` (`Sheets("A")`) activated

```
ws1.Activate
ws1.Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(41, 7)).Formula = ws.Range(ws.Cells(19, 1), ws.Cells(41, 7)).Formula
```

Comment: +1 Nice..  I didn't realise you could directly set formulas like this in blocks of cells.

Comment: @mehow: very good. As usual, I wasted hours for a 2 word code line ! Thank you for your prompt answer.

Comment: Why do you need to Activate ws1? Just fully qualify both sides

Comment: @ooo that's another way of doing it. I think Sid had an answer explaining when you need and when you dont need to activate sheet but I can't find it right now looking through 1636 of his answers :P